# MySQL permissions issue - should be non-issue

Tags: unix, mysql

This is making me kind of crazy:  I did a mysqldump of a partitioned table on one server, moved the resulting SQL dump to another server, and attempted to run the insert.  It fails, but I'm having difficulty figuring out why.  Google and the MySQL forums and docs have not been much help.

The failing query looks like this (truncated for brevity and clarity, names changed to protect the innocent):

```
CREATE TABLE `my_precious_table` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `somedata` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `aTimeStamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`aTimeStamp`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 DATA DIRECTORY='/opt/data/data2/data_foo/' INDEX DIRECTORY='/opt/data/data2/idx_foo/' 
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (year(aTimeStamp)) SUBPARTITION BY HASH ( TO_DAYS(aTimeStamp)) 
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2007) (SUBPARTITION foo0 DATA DIRECTORY = '/opt/data/data2/data_foo' INDEX DIRECTORY = '/opt/data/data2/idx_foo' ENGINE = MyISAM), 
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2008) (SUBPARTITION foo1 DATA DIRECTORY = '/opt/data/data2/data_foo' INDEX DIRECTORY = '/opt/data/data2/idx_foo' ENGINE = MyISAM), 
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2009) (SUBPARTITION foo2 DATA DIRECTORY = '/opt/data/data2/data_foo' INDEX DIRECTORY = '/opt/data/data2/idx_foo' ENGINE = MyISAM), 
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE (SUBPARTITION foo3 DATA DIRECTORY = '/opt/data/data2/data_foo' INDEX DIRECTORY = '/opt/data/data2/idx_foo' ENGINE = MyISAM)) */;
```

The error is:

> ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/opt/data/data2/idx_foo/my_precious_table#P#p0#SP#foo0.MYI' (Errcode: 13)

"Can't create/write to file" looked like a permissions issue to me, but permissions on the targeted folders look thus:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 mysql mysql 4096 Dec  1 16:24 data_foo
drwxrwxrwx 2 mysql mysql 4096 Dec  1 16:25 idx_foo
```

For kicks, I've tried chowning to root:root and myself.  This did not fix the issue.

Source MySQL server is version 5.1.22-rc-log.  Destination server is 5.1.29-rc-community.  Both are running on recent CentOS installations.

**Edit:**  A little more research shows that Errcode 13 is, in fact, a permissions error.  But how can I get that on `rwxrwxrwx`?

**Edit:**  Bill Karwin's excellent suggestion didn't pan out.  I'm working as the root user, and have all privilege flags set.

**Edit:**  Creating the table WITHOUT specifying data directories for the individual partitions works - but I need to put these partitions on a larger disk than the one on which this MySQL instance puts tables by default.  And I can't just specify the DATA/INDEX DIRECTORY at the table level - that's not legit in the version of MySQL I'm using (5.1.29-rc-community).

**Edit:** Finally came across the answer, thanks to the MySQL mailing list and internal IT staff.  See below.

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: Yes.  I've checked this more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be an SElinux issue - all my filesystem permissions were fine, but there was a higher-level policy set against MySQL accessing that disk partition.

Lesson:  When you have a permissions issue but ownership and filesystem permissions are obviously correct, look to SElinux.

Comment: I'm rapidly coming to the opinion that the first thing one should do on any Linux system is `setenforce 0`.

Answer (score 4):

On **Ubuntu** look into the **apparmor** settings for mysql

```
vi /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysql
```

This should solve the permission issues. For a quick test you can even try

```
/etc/init.d/apparmor stop
```

But don't forget to restart the service.

This took me some time to figure out. And after reading "SELinux" it was clear that I have forgotten this new kind of protection on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19557

> You will also receive an error message
>   of the MySQL user ID running the query
>   does not have "DATA FILE" privileges
>   that allows the user ID to write to
>   the file system.

In other words, it can be a permission problem with respect to SQL privileges, not operating system file permissions.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm running as root, and a quick check of the USER table shows that I have all privileges (including File_priv) set true.  Also, the FILE privilege (there isn't one called DATA FILE) lets you use LOAD DATA INFILE and SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE statements - separate issue from table creation.

Comment: Okey dokey, it's good to rule out that possibility.  But I'm not sure what else to suggest.